# using telegram create chat application

Tags: android, api, telegram

I want to create a chating application for android using the telegram API available. I am new to using the external library. Can anybody give me a bit idea about how to use the API to build a chat application?

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
There you will find everything..'
You may also download its source code from github and replace its api id with our api id..